# Writing R code for first 84 days of a non leap year

Tags: r

How do I set up a variable of length 84 that gives the correct month for the first 84 days of a non-leap year (using labels "jan","feb","march")?

Comment: This is a classic case of overthinking.  If you never need a leap year and never need more than 84 days, then just write a lookup table. It'll take you about 3.14159 minutes to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following (change the value of `year` to choose other year):

```
year <- 2001
days <- as.Date(paste(year, "/01/01", sep = "")) + seq.int(0, 83)
months(days, abbreviate = TRUE)
# [1] "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan"
#[13] "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan"
#[25] "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Jan" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb"
#[37] "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb"
#[49] "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Feb" "Mar"
#[61] "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar"
#[73] "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar" "Mar"
```

You can check if the year is a leap year as follows:

```
if (table(months(days))["February"] == 29)
  cat(paste(year, "is a leap year.\n"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Altenative #1:

```
library(zoo)
days <- as.Date('2014-01-01') + seq.int(84)-1
get_month_given_date <- zoo(months(days, abbreviate = TRUE),order.by=days)
#Example
get_month_given_date[as.Date('2014-02-28')]
get_month_given_date[as.Date(c('2014-01-03','2014-03-04'))]
```

Alternative #2:

```
library(zoo)
strsplit(as.character(as.yearmon("2007-03-01"))," ")[[1]][1]
```

Leap year checking:

```
is_leap_year <- function(year){if((year%%4==0 & year%%100!=0) | year%%400==0 ) return(TRUE) else return(FALSE)}
#Examples
is_leap_year(2000)
is_leap_year(1900)
is_leap_year(2012)
is_leap_year(2014)
```